# How to get the interval between two time values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my database I have two columns. First is called `starting` and the other is`ending`. Both are formatted like `11:00`. How to get the interval between ending and starting.

I have tried `whereBetween`, but it didn't work as I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon to get the difference, it offers a number of functions for calculating time differences. For example:

```
$end->diffInSeconds($start);

$end->diffInHours($start);

$end->diffInDays($start);
```

Those are just a few, see [the docs for more examples](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

you have two methods first you can use double where like

```
        $blablabla= Category::
        where('starting','<=','your variable here')
        ->where('ending','>=','your variable here')
        ->first();
```

second method

whereRaw with bindings, where you use the raw condition and a binding for the variable:

```
whereRaw('? between starting and ending', [$yourVariable])
```

BOUNCE 
`wherebetween` is for  check the column value between two given values (intervals)
not the opposite you wanna check given value between two columns